# Why did the kid yelled "Banzai" instead of its Korean equivalent in Squid Game?

Tags: dialogue, squid-game

In the opening scene of the Squid Game, it is shown that after winning the "squid game", a kid yelled *Banzai* in the Korean audio. In this context, it means "victory". But the word *Banzai* is actually a Japanese word (万歳) and in Japanese, it is a battlecry/a form of greeting used to the Japanese emperor. [However, there is a Korean equivalent of the word which is mansé (만세)](https://skdesu.com/en/what-banzai-means/). So, why wasn't this word used in the Korean audio instead of the Japanese word? Is the word that much popular to be used in other (Asian) countries? Or is it due to the fact that the Korean word lacked the punch?

Comment: I see we have 4 close votes and no comment.  Do people that have stated this can "only" be answered through opinion not give any allowance for Korean natives giving a local view on Japanese culture being used in Korea or scriptwriter interviews?

Comment: It may just be because it's a well-known word, world-wide. I've never heard of the Korean word.

Comment: From the "Korea" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_thousand_years#Korea : <<It is also used as a casual proclamation, commonly used as the English equivalent of "Victory.">>

Comment: @iandotkelly I VTCed this as trivia, but I think opinion-based is just as valid: why a character yells something (specific yet) quite well-known as a power term after winning something seems like a character trait. IMO, the lion's share of the question is conjecture.